# Can't use GPU with Pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, anaconda, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I keep getting this error when trying to use Pytorch.

> RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.

I installed Pytorch using `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch`.

With tensorflow my GPU runs just fine.

Comment: [This](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-make-sure-that-pytorch-using-gpu-to-compute/4870/6) might give you an idea.

Comment: what is the version of your nvidia driver?

Comment: What's your CUDA version? To inspect you can type `nvidia-smi` in your terminal.

Comment: @xenotecc pytorch doesn't use system cuda. it installs its own local version

Comment: You are correct. Sorry for the fuss.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this error by installing CUDA 10.2 (The Latest Version) and, additionally re-install Pytorch with this command:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

Answer (score 0):

Use official installation command from `pytorch.org`

For Windows+GPU (for others check `pytorch.org`)

```
pip install torch===1.5.0 torchvision===0.6.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```